# How to override the CharField max_length validation error message that will be responded when sending a post request via API?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a `Customer` model that has a `mobile_phone` field. When I send a post request via API to create a customer with a mobile phone value more than 15 I get that validation error message [**"Ensure this field has no more than 15 characters."**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KZFe.png).
I don't like this message and I would like to override it. Is there a solution to do so?

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=200)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(_('mobile phone'), max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I tried to do something like that

```
def validate_value_lt_fifteen(value):
    if value > 15:
        raise ValidationError(_('Ensure that the mobile phone has no more than 15 characters.'), params={'value': value})


class Customer(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(_('full name'), max_length=200)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(_('mobile phone'),
                                    max_length=15, blank=True, null=True, validators=[validate_value_lt_fifteen])
    ...
```

But unfortunately, it does not solve the problem. On the contrary, it shows both error messages together. [**"Ensure this field has no more than 15 characters."** and **"Ensure that the mobile phone has no more than 15 characters."**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSJ3C.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ModelForm

Override the default error message for validators would solve your problem

```
class CustomerForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        error_messages = {
            'mobile_phone': {
                'max_length': _('Ensure that the mobile phone has no more than 15 characters.'),
            }
        }
```

#### REST API

If you are using `rest_framework`, you could provide the `error_messages` to the `Field` to override the default error message

```
my_default_errors = {'max_length': _('Ensure that the mobile phone has no more than 15 characters.')}

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    mobile_phone = serializer.CharField(error_messages=my_default_errors)

# ModelSerializer
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        extra_kwargs = {"mobile_phone": {"error_messages": {"max_length": _('Ensure that the mobile phone has no more than 15 characters.')}}}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't solve the problem the same error appeared I think this approach works only with forms

Comment: @AmeerAbdulaziz yeah，one mistake, this should be added to `ModelForm`

Comment: ModelSerializer part works perfectly, thanks, @minglyu!